# Creating new dataframes using like values in an existing dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

So I have a dataframe (df1) of phone records roughly 10k+ rows long with calls from different phone numbers on the same day and the same phone number on different days. (Example of df1)

| Date | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1234567891 |
| 01/01/2022 | 1234567892 |
| 01/02/2022 | 1234567891 |
| 01/02/2022 | 1234567893 |
| 01/02/2022 | 1234567892 |

What I want to do write a short script that will iterate over df1 to group the rows by unique phone number and create a new dataframe for each unique phone number.

Now the kicker is I will have to do this periodically do df1 will fluctuate in length and content so simply sorting df1 and assigning rows 1-10 to df2 and 11-33 to df3 wont work.

So far I have only come up with a way to isolate each number 1 at a time manually

`df2= df1[df['Number'].isin([1234567891])]`

Comment: Try [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all unique phonenumbers from your dataframe into a list:

```
numbers = df['Number'].unique()
```

Now you can iterate over this list and extract the dataframe for each phonenumber. In this example I print the dataframe:

```
for number in numbers:
    print(df[df['Number'] == number])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider following simple example which make use of `.groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['A','B','A','A','C'],'value':[5,4,3,2,1]})
grouped = df.groupby('user')
user_df = {}
for user in df.user.unique():
    user_df[user] = grouped.get_group(user)
```

Now `user_df` is `dict` with 3 DataFrames, 1 for each user, so

```
print(user_df['A'])
```

gives output

```
  user  value
0    A      5
2    A      3
3    A      2
```

and

```
print(user_df['B'])
```

gives output

```
  user  value
1    B      4
```

and

```
print(user_df['C'])
```

gives output

```
  user  value
4    C      1
```

If you need to process 1 user per each loop turn do

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['A','B','A','A','C'],'value':[5,4,3,2,1]})
grouped = df.groupby('user')
for user in df.user.unique():
    user_df = grouped.get_group(user) # user_df is now pandas.DataFrame
    print(user, user_df['value'].min(), user_df['value'].max())
```

gives output

```
A 2 5
B 4 4
C 1 1
```

Comment: So I like this and it worked, but is there a way to automatically iterate over the dictionary and convert each key into its own DataFrame. I know I can manually do this using pandas and hand jamming each phone number in to a `pd.DateFrame(user_df['C'])` but my dictionary could have 20+ keys and would be time consuming to do manually.

Comment: @Tony you might elect to do `user_df = grouped.get_group(user)` inside `for` loop and then use `user_df` DataFrame inside that loop

Comment: I'm sorry I am fairly new to python, how would using `user_df` within the for loop look? I used the code you provided above to create my dictionary.